# Calculating the length

Tags: arcpy

Can someone break this script in to a few lines so that I know what I am doing?

I understand the code about finding the length of a Polyline, but how to break this into step by step?

Here is the long line script:

```
a[f[0] for f in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("polyline.shp", 'SHAPE@LENGTH')][0]
```

and as a beginner I want it something like this:

```
for f in cursor:
     print("The length of Polyline is", "SHAPE@LENGTH")[0]
```

But I am not sure if I can get a result from this, and what does `[0]` do here?

Comment: Thanks much! I get a result from your script too. However I already have a line above your script which says:
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ['ID','SHAPE@']) 
So, now can I make a bit more simpler than that?

Comment: Please do not post thanks or code in comments. If you need to clarify the question it should be done within the body of the question. The [Someone answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) page of the [help] discusses policy on thanks and the purpose of comments.

Answer (score 2):

You will need something like the following.

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("polyline.shp", "SHAPE@LENGTH") as cursor: 
    for f in cursor: 
        print ("The length of the polyline is: ", f[0])
```

The `[0]` in this case refers to the the first available field in the cursor (`"SHAPE@LENGTH"`)

If you use a list of fields, they can be accessed by their index in the cursor, e.g.:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("polyline.shp", ["SHAPE@LENGTH","OBJECTID"]) as cursor: 
    for f in cursor: 
        print ("The length of the polyline is: ", f[0], " The Object ID of the polyline is: ", f[1])
```

To get a list of all the fields which you can then pass into the cursor:

```
fields = []
field_objects = arcpy.ListFields("polyline.shp")`
for obj in field_objects:
    fields.append(obj.name)
```

You can then use `fields` as follows:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("polyline.shp", fields) as cursor: 
    for f in cursor:
         # access any field by its index (starting at 0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Matt! How if we want to open the same file, print out the attribute and the attribute data types of layer. 
can we still use:
arcpy.da.SearchCursor?

Comment: Using `with` means that the cursor is automatically closed after every row has been iterated over (there is no need to delete the cursor later). You can do as much as you want regarding the attributes provided a) your code is within the `with` block and b) you specify the fields you want to extract attribute values from. `f` in your case is a single row of the table that the cursor iterates through.

Alternatively, you can open a new cursor after this one if you need to.

Comment: Thanks! For OGR we can simply use a one line script to list the fields name and their data type as such: 
for field in layer.schema:
    print(field.name, field.GetTypeName())
Do we have something like this in ArcPy?

Comment: You're most welcome. Apologies for the slow response, I was in the middle of updating my answer when my internet went down. See third and fourth code block above.